# SelectManyCheckbox onHide with remoteCommand

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I ran into a very interesting issue. Here is my scenario:

**My Goal**

- Use a SelectManyCheckbox with a nested tooltip.
- Use SelectManyCheckbox onHide event to fire an Ajax (ActionListener) call
  and update the
- SelectManyCheckbox label and nested tooltip text.

**My Approach**

- Use a remoteCommand and tie it to the SelectManyCheckbox onHide event

**XHTML**

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="sourceFilter"
                onHide="sourceFilterCommand();"
                value="#{viewRevenueBean.sourceSelectManyMenu.selectedValues}" 
                label="#{viewRevenueBean.sourceSelectManyMenu.label}"
                filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
                validator="#{viewRevenueBean.sourceSelectManyMenu.validate}"
                widgetVar="srcFilterDropDown">
                <f:selectItems id="sourceItems"
                              value="#{viewRevenueBean.sourceSelectManyMenu.availableItems}" 
                              var="source" itemLabel="#{source.label}" itemValue="#{source.value}" />
                <f:convertNumber type="number" />
                                    <p:tooltip id="srcToolTip" 
                                for="sourceFilter" 
                        value="#{viewRevenueBean.sourceSelectManyMenu.tooltipText}" 
                        showEffect="fade" 
                            hideEffect="fade"/>
                <p:remoteCommand name="sourceFilterCommand" update="sourceFilter"
                    actionListener=#{viewRevenueBean.sourceSelectManyMenu.defaultEventHandler}"/>       
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

**My Results**

- Ajax (Action Listener) gets fired and SelectManyCheckbox label and nested tooltip are updated (expected behavior).
- In Firebug, I noticed that each onHide event Ajax call is multiplying the preceding number of server side requests by two (unexpected behavior).

**e.g**

```
1st onHide event  = 1 Request
2nd onHide event  = 2 Requests
3rd onHide event  = 4 Requests  
4th onHide event  = 8 Requests  
5th onHide event  = 16 Requests
```

etc.....

This is obviously not desired and leads to a big slow down after just
   a couple onHide events.

**Experiments I tried**

- I created a p:command button which accomplished the desired Ajax call and correct element updates (without the multiplied request
  issue) . I then proceeded to steal it's Ajax JavaScript call via
  Firebug and placed it in my own JavaScript function, which I then
  used as my onHide callback.  Again, I experience the same unwanted
  result, the label and tooltip are updated, but the requests start to
  multiply.
- I tried placing the remoteCommand in different locations
  (outside the menu, inside it's own form etc). It doesn't make a
  difference. The problem is still encountered.
- I tried simplifying the SelectManyCheckbox scenario (remove
  tooltip, coverter, tweak various attributes etc) to eliminate other
  possibilities. No difference.
- I tried a p:ajax instead of p:remoteCommand using onchange.
  The Ajax requests work fine but obviously it's not what  I am after.
  I need to trigger it onHide.
- Instead of a SelectCheckboxMenu , i tried using a
  SelectManyCheckbox (no label) with onchange and keeping everything
  else the same. The remoteCommand works fine, the Ajax call gets
  called once and everything is nice and dandy.  [/list] [list] * I
  tried the PrimeFaces 3.5-SNAPSHOT as well. No difference. Issue is
  still manifested.

  Haven't found any clues on the forum or the net thus far in regards
  to this issue. Does this sound like a bug or programmer clumsiness 
  :roll: ?  Of course any insight and/or suggestions are highly
  appreciated.

Comment: i have faced this issue and at the end of the day i found out that it's because of the collision of widgetVar within my application

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar problems when using p:remoteCommand. I can't say for sure that the root cause is the same in your case, but maybe this can help somewhat.

In my case the problem was caused by multiplied registering of jquery bindings; the p:remoteCommand seem not to use $(somesource).off("some_event").on("some_event", some_function). That means - as far as I have understood - that if you update the component containing the p:remoteCommand, it's action will be registered over and over again, each time it's being updated. That in turn will mean that if you call on the name of the p:remoteCommand, it will fire the same amount of times as it's been registered.

You said you'd tried to move it outside and still got the same problem, so maybe it's not this problem after all. In my case I tested this assumption using a p:commandLink instead and had that call the backing bean. The goal for me was to make sure that any previous registration of a binding was removed, so through registering the binding like mentioned above:

$(somesource).off("some_event").on("some_event", some_function), and let some_function click the link, you can at least check if it solves the problem.